# How to use a toggle to Start/Stop recording onSensorChanged data to SQLite?

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite, android-sensors

I am trying to develop an app which stores accelerometer and gyroscope data into an SQLite database. I have already done the basic thing of getting the accelerometer and gyroscope to work. I have also managed to create a working database that continuously records the data when the application is on with timestamps included. The problem I am having now is I want to include a toggle to Start/Stop recording data to the database to save battery and memory, but I could not get it to work properly. I have tried using **onCheckedChanged()** to see if the toggle is pressed or not, but that only adds one line of data into the database.  What I want is when the Toggle is pressed, the database should be filled with sensor data until the Toggle is pressed again. Is there any way to do this? Any feedback would be useful. Thanks

```
// for accessing accelerometer and gyroscope sensors and displaying them

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener , SensorEventListener {

    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private TextView xText, yText , zText, xTextGyro, yTextGyro , zTextGyro;
    private ToggleButton toggle;
    private Sensor accelerometer;
    private Sensor gyroscope;
    private SensorManager sM;
    private SensorEventListener accelerometerListener,gyroscopeEventListener;
    public float accelX, accelY, accelZ, gyroX, gyroY, gyroZ;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        //Assign TextViews to specific axises
        xText =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xText);
        yText =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yText);
        zText =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zText);


        xTextGyro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xTextGyro);
        yTextGyro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yTextGyro);
        zTextGyro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zTextGyro);

        toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);   //toggle for start/stop recording

        //Creating the sensor manager; SENSOR_SERVICE is used to access sensors.
        sM = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        //Accelerometer Sensor.
        accelerometer = sM.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        if(accelerometer != null){

            //Register sensor listener;
            sM.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate initializing sensors");

        } else{
            xText.setText("Accelerometer not supported");
            yText.setText("Accelerometer not supported");
            zText.setText("Accelerometer not supported");
        }


        //GYRO Sensor.
        gyroscope = sM.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);

        if(gyroscope != null){

            //Register sensor listener;
            sM.registerListener(this, gyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate initializing sensors");

        } else{
            xTextGyro.setText("GYROSCOPE not supported");
            yTextGyro.setText("GYROSCOPE not supported");
            zTextGyro.setText("GYROSCOPE not supported");
        }


@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor sensorType = event.sensor;

          if(sensorType.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            xText.setText("X: " + event.values[0]);
            yText.setText("Y: " + event.values[1]);
            zText.setText("Z: " + event.values[2]);

            accelX = event.values[0];
            accelY = event.values[1];
            accelZ = event.values[2];


        }  else if (sensorType.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE){
            xTextGyro.setText("X: " + event.values[0]);
            yTextGyro.setText("Y: " + event.values[1]);
            zTextGyro.setText("Z: " + event.values[2]);

           gyroX = event.values[0];
           gyroY = event.values[1];
           gyroZ = event.values[2];
        }

        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(toggle.isChecked()){

                    DatabaseHelper.getInstance().insertTable(accelX, accelY, accelZ, gyroX, gyroY, gyroZ);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording data...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });
```

My DatabaseHelper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    
    public static final String SENSOR_TABLE = "SENSOR_TABLE";
    public static final String COLUMN_ACCEL_X = "ACCEL_X";
    public static final String COLUMN_ACCEL_Y = "ACCEL_Y";
    public static final String COLUMN_ACCEL_Z = "ACCEL_Z";
    
    public static final String COLUMN_GYRO_X = "GYRO_X";
    public static final String COLUMN_GYRO_Y = "GYRO_Y";
    public static final String COLUMN_GYRO_Z = "GYRO_Z";

    private static DatabaseHelper mInstance;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "AccelButton.db", null, 1);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(){
        if(mInstance == null){
            synchronized (DatabaseHelper.class){
                if(mInstance == null){
                    mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(BaseApp.getApp());
                }
            }
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //String createTableStatement= "CREATE TABLE " + SENSOR_TABLE + "( " +  COLUMN_ACCEL_X + " REAL, " + COLUMN_ACCEL_Y + " REAL, " + COLUMN_ACCEL_Z + " REAL, time DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME)";
        String createTableStatement= "CREATE TABLE " + SENSOR_TABLE + "( time DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME, " +  COLUMN_ACCEL_X + " REAL, " + COLUMN_ACCEL_Y + " REAL, " + COLUMN_ACCEL_Z + " REAL, " + COLUMN_GYRO_X + " REAL, " + COLUMN_GYRO_Y + " REAL, " + COLUMN_GYRO_Z + " REAL)";
        db.execSQL(createTableStatement);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+SENSOR_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public void insertTable(float x, float y, float z ,float a, float b , float c){  //put onSensorChanged data to database

        ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();
        contentvalues.put("ACCEL_X", x);
        contentvalues.put("ACCEL_Y", y);
        contentvalues.put("ACCEL_Z", z);

        contentvalues.put("GYRO_X", a);
        contentvalues.put("GYRO_Y", b);
        contentvalues.put("GYRO_Z", c);


        getWritableDatabase().insert(SENSOR_TABLE, null, contentvalues);



    }
}
```

My BaseApp class:

```
public class BaseApp extends Application {

        private static BaseApp mInstance ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;

    }

    public static Application getApp(){
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The toggle listener you added will report "onchange" so only when the user taps that button. You should do as little as possible inside the onsensorchanged. Remove the toggle, and place it somewhere else like the oncreate.

Set a flag to keep track of when the toggle is activated:

```
boolean flagToggle = false;

   if(toggle.isChecked()){
        //do stuff when Switch is ON
    flagToggle = true

    } else {
        //do stuff when Switch if OFF
flagToggle = false
    }
```

On your onsensorchanged you can just have:

```
if(flagToggle){
DatabaseHelper.getInstance().insertTable(accelX, accelY, accelZ, gyroX, gyroY, gyroZ);
}
```

The data should now be inserted into the database. I recommend that you refactor this code, and move it outside of the onsensorchanged.

Comment: I have done what u advised, setting a flag to keep track of the toggle during activation, i placed it inside the "onCreate". i also put the ' if(flagToggle)' statement inside 'onSensorChanged' but what happens is it creates the table, but it does not insert the value of the sensors. Am i doing something wrong? I'm new to all this so I really appreciate the help